# CUPS not supporting printing any filetype in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, printing

When I try to print any file, I receive

```
$ tail -f /var/log/cups/error_log

[Client 396] Returning IPP client-error-document-format-not-supported for Send-Document (ipp://localhost:631/printers/M2070) from localhost

$ lpstat -tdo
scheduler is running
system default destination: M2070
device for M2070: usb://Samsung/M2070%20Series?serial=ZF44B8KJCB00TWP&interface=1
M2070 accepting requests since Mon 29 Apr 2019 01:49:02 CEST
printer M2070 is idle.  enabled since Mon 29 Apr 2019 01:49:02 CEST
system default destination: M2070

$ sudo grep -rn pdf .
./cups-browsed.conf:264:# BrowseFilter pdl postscript|pcl|pdf
./mime.types:69:application/pdf         pdf regex(0,^[\n\r]*%PDF)
./mime.types:149:application/vnd.cups-pdf

$ lsusb | grep Samsung
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04e8:3469 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd

$ lpr test #didn't start printing

$ lp -d M2070 -oraw test #started printing, but printed only half of the last line
request id is M2070-12 (1 file(s))
```

On http://localhost:631/ I can see that CUPS 2.2.7 is installed.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is it a laptop? Is it dual booted? If so, did Samsung M2070 print on windows 10? Please reply. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's laptop, Lenovo Legion Y530-15ICH. No dual boot, only Pop OS 18.04 (based on Ubuntu 18.04). On another laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 printer is working fine

Comment: To bypass all these filters and let the data go directly to the printer, without any changes or conversions, issue the following print command `lp -d <printQueueName> -oraw <sample-text-file>`. Please observe that this command prints successfully. Please report.

Comment: Please post the output of the command `lsusb`

Comment: I added output to the question. `lsusb` see the printer. `lp ...` initiated printing (nice!) but the file wasn't printed properly (not nice)

Comment: Please post the output of the commands: 1. `ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/008` 2. `lpstat -p M2070 -l` 3. `groups` and 4. `id $whoami`. You can access printers using GUI: Settings -> Devices -> Printers. After reaching `Printers` through GUI, first remove printer `M2070`, then save and exit `Settings`. Now confirm the removal of printer with command `lpstat -p`. Again enter into `Settings` and reach `Printers`. Now add the printer M2070 afresh, then save and exit `Settings`. Confirm the addition of printer with `lpstat -p` command. Try a test print. Please report. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Legacy (non-modern) printers require printer drivers.

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-all
sudo systemctl restart cups
```

Also, make sure your printer is being added in **Settings > Printers**

[image: Ubuntu printers settings]

You could also add the printer from the cups web interface at `localhost:631`.

Under administration click on **Find New Printers**. If your printer is plugged in you'd find it under the local printers.

[image: Cups add printer]